# Is Code Review the site to ask for code examples?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, code-review-se

Is Code Review the site to ask for code examples?   For example, if I need some examples for threads, which site would I go to ask for them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot ask that question anywhere on the network.

Code Review is for *working code* that you want reviewed; people will suggest improvements. It is not a site to ask for examples. Quoting from the [*What topics can I ask here* section of their help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Code Review Stack Exchange is for **sharing code from projects you are working on** for peer review. If you are looking for feedback on a specific **working** piece of code from your project in the following areas [...] then you are in the right place!
>
> However, if your question is not about a particular piece of code [...] then your question is **off-topic** for this site.

Asking for examples is too broad and in practice results in a lot of low-quality answers (often including spam). As such such questions are off-topic for Stack Exchange sites; many include an explicit off-topic close reason for it.

Answer (score 5):

To add briefly, you can *find* lots of good code examples, as well as reviews on best practices, by clicking [**Tags** on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags) or StackOverflow and searching for a topic, for example [[multithreading]](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multithreading). That for example brings up 9 pages worth of working code examples along with reviews, and it's a great way to learn things.

You can use the Search bar to combine multiple tags, too. For example, search for [`[multithreading] [java]`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multithreading+java) to find code that is tagged with both.

Just don't come asking *gimme-the-codez* on Stack Exchange, as this will make your question get closed automagically :)

Answer (score 2):

If you can describe the problem you're having implementing or understanding threads, go to http://StackOverflow.com

If you can think of a way to make it into a programming challenge, either solving a puzzle, code golf (smallest code to perform a function), or performance related, you might find an audience at https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The solutions you would get from Code Golf would probably be poor examples to learn from.

Comment: @200_success Probably!